# Populate selectize.js field without triggering item_add event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, selectize.js

How do you `selectize.addItem("value")` without triggering `item_add`?

---

I have a tags field that’s dependent on another selection. I need to automatically fill in tags whenever that other selection is changed, and then I need to have a listener run code whenever the user adds or removes a tag. I can’t figure out how to add the tags programmatically without triggering the `item_add` event, but I don’t want it triggering before the user’s even touched the tags.

(There is `addItem(…, silent)`, but unless I’m mistaken, that only stops it from triggering the `change` event.)

Sample code:

```js
$('#input-tags').selectize({
  onItemAdd: function() {
    alert("This should only appear by user action");
  }
});
$tags = $('#input-tags')[0].selectize;
$tags.addItem("awesome");
$tags.addItem("neat");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36chjdf0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

One solution (and the only one I know of) is to remove the event listeners before the `addItem`s and add them back afterwards. That hardly seems ideal, though, especially if it needs to be done more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your code to register the add callback after adding all initial values:

```
$('#input-tags').selectize();
$tags = $('#input-tags')[0].selectize;
$tags.addItem("awesome");
$tags.addItem("neat");
// Register the listener once you have initialized the selectize component.
$tags.on('item_add', function() {
    alert("This should only appear by user action");
});
```

Comment: Isn’t this what I described in my own answer? Which, again, you’d have to remove and re-add the callback each time the other selection is changed and the values get repopulated, since that repopulation would call the callback.

Comment: Well.. not really. In my solution, there is no item_add listener at the time of creation, rather it is introduced after addition of values. So, this does not require explicit removal of listener. As per your question, you are passing the listener while initialization, and hence, you would need to remove it explicitly.